# Segmentation Fault with Symfony 4.1, PHP 7.1.2x

Tags: php, symfony, segmentation-fault

After installing Symfony 4.1.3 on a box running SLES 12.3 with PHP 7.1.20 (and later upgraded to 7.1.21), Apache child processes began segmentation faulting. This happens several times per hour seemingly randomly.

```
[Fri Sep 07 09:57:01.166821 2018] [core:notice] [pid 10004:tid 139775548520192] AH00052: child pid 7164 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I cannot discern any particular pattern to the madness, only that it could potentially have something to do with Symfony's interaction with phpenv (based on the dump below).

Background to the purpose of this Symfony install: Used as a general CRUD application with API endpoints which spit out JSON data. I am using "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3" to handle the API. The API endpoints themselves are pretty straightforward. Here is an example of one:

```
public function getExternalRedirectAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $url = $request->query->get('url');

    $redirect = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Redirect::class)->findOneBy(['fromLink' => $url]);

    if (!$redirect) {
        $response = new Response(json_encode("The redirect you requested was not found."), 404, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        return $response;
    }

    $redirect->setVisits($redirect->getVisits() + 1);
    $redirect->setLastVisit(new \DateTime());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($redirect);
    $em->flush();

    $context = new SerializationContext();
    $context->setSerializeNull(true);

    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
    $serialized = $serializer->serialize($redirect, 'json', $context);

    $response = new Response($serialized, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));

    return $response;
}
```

Here is a full backtrace following a seg fault.

```
(gdb) backtrace full 
#0  0x00007fedcc1162b3 in __strchr_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007fedcc0cc0c8 in putenv () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007fedc616a85c in php_putenv_destructor (zv=0x7fed96ad59a0)
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/ext/standard/basic_functions.c:3435
        pe = 0x7fed96afaa40
#3  0x00007fedc63afc65 in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x7fed8c0e4328)
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/Zend/zend_hash.c:1246
        p = 0x7fed96ad59a0
        end = 0x7fed96ad5a80
#4  0x00007fedc616c467 in zm_deactivate_basic (type=1, module_number=33)
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/ext/standard/basic_functions.c:3811
No locals.
#5  0x00007fedc63a43ad in zend_deactivate_modules ()
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/Zend/zend_API.c:2576
        module = 0xdfd070
        p = 0xf85808
        __orig_bailout = 0x0
        __bailout = {{__jmpbuf = {140658233296848, 1066617060162552172, 
              140658502012712, 140659038370920, 140659038370104, 
              140659038370752, 1066617060149969260, 1066664924020097388}, 
            __mask_was_saved = 0, __saved_mask = {__val = {
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
                1066664949417394540, 140655883976704, 140659220598624, 
                15867216, 18446744064156967775, 15866640, 77753426461, 
                140658845055312, 140659209739746, 140658845055344, 
                140658233298472, 140658845055344, 0, 140658845055328, 
                140659209527934, 0}}}}
#6  0x00007fedc62d8638 in php_request_shutdown (dummy=0x0)
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/main/main.c:1876
        report_memleaks = 1 '\001'
#7  0x00007fedc648d467 in php_apache_request_dtor (r=0x7fed9c0c0f28)
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:552
No locals.
#8  0x00007fedc648df8a in php_handler (r=0x7fed9c0c0f28)
    at /usr/local/src/php-7.1.21/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:724
        ctx = 0x7fed781b6810
        conf = 0xd82a70
        brigade = 0x7fed9c195330
        bucket = 0xdcba00
        rv = 0
        parent_req = 0x0
#9  0x0000000000455850 in ap_run_handler (r=r@entry=0x7fed9c0c0f28)
    at config.c:170
        pHook = <optimized out>
        n = 5
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
        rv = -1
#10 0x0000000000455d99 in ap_invoke_handler (r=r@entry=0x7fed9c0c0f28)
    at config.c:444
        handler = <optimized out>
        p = <optimized out>
        result = <optimized out>
        old_handler = 0x0
        ignore = <optimized out>
#11 0x000000000046aa4c in ap_internal_redirect (new_uri=<optimized out>, 
    r=<optimized out>) at http_request.c:791
        access_status = <optimized out>
        new = 0x7fed9c0c0f28
#12 0x00007fedc701d25c in handler_redirect (r=0x7fed9c0c2800)
    at mod_rewrite.c:5256
No locals.
#13 0x0000000000455850 in ap_run_handler (r=r@entry=0x7fed9c0c2800)
    at config.c:170
        pHook = <optimized out>
        n = 4
        rv = -1
#14 0x0000000000455d99 in ap_invoke_handler (r=r@entry=0x7fed9c0c2800)
    at config.c:444
        handler = <optimized out>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
        p = <optimized out>
        result = <optimized out>
        old_handler = 0x7fedc7025e14 "redirect-handler"
        ignore = <optimized out>
#15 0x000000000046b6da in ap_process_async_request (r=0x7fed9c0c2800)
    at http_request.c:453
        access_status = 0
#16 0x0000000000467c51 in ap_process_http_async_connection (c=0x7fedbc043c68)
    at http_core.c:154
        r = 0x7fed9c0c2800
        cs = 0x7fedbc043c30
#17 ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7fedbc043c68) at http_core.c:248
No locals.
#18 0x000000000045f380 in ap_run_process_connection (c=c@entry=0x7fedbc043c68)
    at connection.c:42
        pHook = <optimized out>
        n = 2
        rv = -1
#19 0x0000000000472dca in process_socket (thd=<optimized out>, 
    p=<optimized out>, sock=<optimized out>, cs=0x7fedbc043bc0, 
    my_child_num=<optimized out>, my_thread_num=<optimized out>)
    at event.c:1048
        c = 0x7fedbc043c68
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
        conn_id = <optimized out>
        clogging = <optimized out>
        rv = <optimized out>
        rc = 0
#20 0x0000000000474348 in worker_thread (thd=0xd23a78, dummy=<optimized out>)
    at event.c:2122
        csd = 0x7fedbc0439c0
        cs = 0x0
        te = 0x0
        ptrans = 0x7fedbc043938
        ti = <optimized out>
        process_slot = 3
        thread_slot = 24
        rv = <optimized out>
        is_idle = 0
#21 0x00007fedcc646724 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#22 0x00007fedcc181e8d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause of the segmentation fault but, Symfony 4.0 (and above) requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher to run, in addition to other minor requirements, according to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/requirements.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. We currently have 7.1.21, so we're past 7.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue of colliding child processes between mod_ssl and mod_php. After lots of experimentation, we ended up sending all incoming requests into mod_ssl to php_fpm. We also set up opcache and swapped out the default openssl version on our box with openssl v1.1.0.